# How can I remove the Private Flag from hundreds of messages in shared mailboxes?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2013, flag

I work with an Outlook 2010 x86 Client and an Exchange 2013 Server. In many "*Shared Mailboxes*" are some Mails with a "*Private Flag*" and it is not possible to read this mails in Outlook 2010. With the MFCMAPI-Editor is it possible to clean this "*Private Flag*"  one by one, but I have hundreds of mails. The mail property is `PR_SENSITIVITY`, `PidTagSensitivity`, and `ptagSensitivity`.

I tried to write a VBA script that set the sensitivity from "*Private*" to "*Normal*", but I have big problems to write VBA script´s.

Is it possible with a VBA script, or is there an existing a method do this with the Exchange Powershell?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You said you tried to write VBA and "*have big problems*". Can you define what that means for us? Please include your current code and what error messages you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your fast comment CharlieRB. Thats my code:

```vb
Sub ClearPrivateFlag()
    Dim ol As New Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim fdMail As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objAppt As MailItem
    Dim i, nCount As Integer

    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Reference the default Mail folder
    Set fdMail = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 1
    nCount = fdMail.Items.Count

    Do While i < nCount
      Set objItem = fdMail.Items(i)

      If objItem.Class = olMailItem Then
          Set objAppt = objItem
          If (objAppt.Sensitivity = olPrivate) Then
              objAppt.Sensitivity = olNormal
              MsgBox objAppt
          End If
      End If

      i = i + 1
      Set objItem = Nothing
      Set objAppt = Nothing
    Loop

    Set fdCalendar = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set ol = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You should edit your original comment and add this.

Comment: This will work for one default mailbox only and only for Inbox. OP asked for a way to process shared mailboxes.

Comment: I excute this in the Inbox, but nothing happens.